# Isometries in $\mathbb{E}^2$

Tags: geometry, functions, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, isometry

We define $\mathbb{E}^2 = (\mathbb{R}^2, d_E)$, where $d_E$ is the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

We say that a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, where $X, Y$ are metric spaces, is an isometry if it is surjective and $\forall x, y \in X: d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x, y)$.

So I understand that, for example, in $\mathbb{E}^2$, the function $f(x) = x + a$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is an isometry (a translation).

How can I understand the following question?

> Is the following function an isometry of of $\mathbb{E}^2$?
>
> $f(x,y) =(y,x)$

I'm not sure how to deal with this because $f$ seems to go from $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: It looks like your functions takes an ordered pair to an ordered pair, so $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I never thought of looking at it that way (thanks for that). So in that case, $f$ is not an isometry right?

Comment: Have you checked if it is surjective and preserves the metric?

Comment: I didn't check subjectivity since the easiest thing to first check was that it preserves the metric. Which it doesn't (I think) because $d(f((x_1,x_2)),f((y_1,y_2))) = d((x_2,x_1),(y_2,y_1)) \neq d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))$.

Comment: Try writing out the definition of distance and see if you can rearrange it.

Comment: you know the formula of the usual metric, so use it to find explicit expressions for the distances.

Comment: if $(x',y') \in \mathbb{E}^2$, can you find $ (x,y) \in \mathbb{E}^2$ such that $f(x,y)=(x',y')$? If you can, your function is surjective.

Comment: @N.Owad So what I've tried is: $d(f((x_1,x_2)),f((y_1,y_2))) = d((x_2,x_1),(y_2,y_1)) = |(x_2 - y_2, x_1 - y_1)| = \sqrt{(x_2 - y_2)^2 + (x_1 - y_1)^2}$, but continuing from here doesn't seem to help... should I try something else?

Comment: @LuisVera Surjectivity seems to hold trivially, right?

Comment: Now calculate $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))$ and compare both.

Comment: and for surjectivity, can you give me the explicit value of $(x,y)$ that solves the equation I wrote?

Comment: @LuisVera Using the fact that addition is commutative did the trick, thanks. For surjectivity, taking $(x,y) = (y', x')$ seems to do the trick. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct! You solved it.

Comment: @LuisVera Thank you for your help! If you'd like some rep, please do go ahead and post an answer so I can accept it and remove this from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb{E}^2$, then $(y,x)\in \mathbb{E}^2$ and $f(y,x)=(x,y)$, so  $f$ is surjective.

Let $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb{E}^2$, then $f(x_1,y_1)=(y_1,x_1)$ and $f(x_2,y_2)=(y_2,x_2)$ and

$$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))= \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2}$$
$$d(f(x_1,y_1),f(x_2,y_2))= d((y_1,x_1),(y_2,x_2))=\sqrt{(y_1-y_2)^2 + (x_1-x_2)^2} $$

Since addition is commutative we have that $f$ preserves metric and hence is an isometry.